# Force closest facilities take the same route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, dijkstra

I have a routing problem that I intend to solve with ArcGIS network analyst. First, Closest facility works perfect for me to find the shortest paths to a number of demands. The results look like the left part of the figure:

[image]

For my analysis I would like to compare the left situation with the right one, when it is more cost-efficient to share the route. This far I have just painted the routes in the right part for clarity. In a normal Dijkstra I would just recursively adapt the weights of the links, setting the already chosen to a lower cost. However, I do not know how could I do this in ArcGIS closest facility.

Is there a way to modify the shortest path algorithm in Network analyst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make modifications to the Closest Facility solver directly from ArcMap without writing your own solver with ArcObjects and say Visual C++ or C#. Look for more details here [Custom solver](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Custom_Solver/000100000n99000000/).

However, there is a simpler approach. If you are OK with some Python scripting, this is what you could do with arcpy (Python programming) to tackle this problem:

1. Take any of the incident points and solve Route problem finding the shortest/fastest path from the incident to each facility. Find the best route (compare the total travel time / km).
2. Find out what road links have been traversed by this particular route. There is even a [GP tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/copy-traversed-source-features.htm) for that.
3. [Load](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/add-locations.htm) those line features as [scaled-cost barriers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/barriers.htm) in the same Route network layer. You can specify factor of 0-0.9 to make the cost of traversing the same road links smaller. So if traversing a road link costed 10min, with factor 0.6 it will be just 6 min. This means that the road links which have been traversed by the first incident-facility route will be more attractive to subsequent routes.
4. Repeat the step 1 taking next incident point and the facilities present. Having scaled-cost barriers loaded, the traversed road links will be more attractive to the routes generated.

The steps above can be easily automated with arcpy. Please take a look at this [sample](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-network-analyst/getnaclassnames.htm).

Comment: thank you! The second way is pretty much, what I was thinking about.

Comment: No problem! If you stuck at some point of implementing the workflow, please do post a question we could take a look.