# Dynamically updating path weights with route in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, dijkstra

I am trying to force the routing to reuse as many path parts as possible as described in [initial question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174200/force-closest-facilities-take-the-same-route/174222?noredirect=1#comment261294_174222). The submodel for it is as follows:

[image: submodel]

What it supposed to do is as follows:

1. The path from the first iteration is precalculated with normal "Route" in network analyst and given to this model as initial value for "previously chosen route"
2. Then the iterator goes through the rest of the points and calculates the shortest path under scaled cost (0.1) for the already chosen route segments
3. The feedback is supposed to dynamically update the chosen route list

The add scaled cost is modeled as follows:
[image: add_scaled_cost]

There I have also chosen the option to Append to existing to make the list of previously chosen routes.

**The problem is that this dynamic update does not work** and I do not know, why. 
The model starts showing that there is not enough input parameters and at the same time Copy features does not create any new layers, so practically only the initial input route stays and the rest of output is not created. The iteration and merging is working fine.

The model works, when I remove the feedback link, but this is not what I want.

Comment: You are saying that the model doesn't have enough input parameters? Can you tell me wich ones are missing? Second you are saying that Copy features doesn't add any layers. Did you checked the option "Add to display"?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I tried myself, and could not get it to work either